# Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat go.mod

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerode

What I am trying to do:
**To build a docker image from inside Go/node routine**

My docker file is:

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -v -o /usr/local/bin/app ./...

EXPOSE 3333


CMD ["app"]
```

It is located in the same directory where I am running the build command. `docker build .` works just fine.

The problem appears when I am trying to build the Dockerfile from inside of a Go module(or a node module) using docker client SDK.

Full error is:

```
{"stream":"Step 1/11 : FROM golang:1.18"}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e e3c0472b1b62\n"}
{"stream":"Step 2/11 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app"}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Using cache\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e 6a67704c8a3f\n"}
{"stream":"Step 3/11 : RUN ls /usr/src/app"}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Running in d6104ab4f79c\n"}
{"stream":"Removing intermediate container d6104ab4f79c\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e eddfe3069e8e\n"}
{"stream":"Step 4/11 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./"}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat go.mod: file does not exist"},"error":"COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat go.mod: file does not exist"}
```

Note: I have tried this with both Go-SDK and npm/dockerode module. Same error in both places.

Do I need to make changes to the dockerfile?

Go program that builds this is as follows:

```
func buildImage() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    dockerClient, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    tar, err := archive.TarWithOptions("./Dockerfile", &archive.TarOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    opts := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Dockerfile:  "Dockerfile",
        Tags:        []string{"myproject" + "/fromgo"},
        Remove:      true,
    }
    res, err := dockerClient.ImageBuild(ctx, tar, opts)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    type stream struct{
        stream string
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(res.Body)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you setting the context to when building in the Docker client SDK?

Comment: @tentative. Thanks for the reply. `ctx := context.Background()`. I have updated the desription above with the entire function body.

Comment: @tentative. The problem looks to have been solved. 
On Line#7 I changed the path to point to the root(instead of `‘Dockerfile’` earlier).        `tar, err := archive.TarWithOptions("./", &archive.TarOptions{})`

This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Path to the root of the project updated. This solved the problem. Root cause may have been `archive.TarWithOptions`, not docker-sdk itself.

```
    tar, err := archive.TarWithOptions("./", &archive.TarOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: One point to note: The only working configuration at this point is to keep a file named "Dockerfile" at the root i.e. "./" of the project. Deviation from these 2 rules will fail the above Tar statement and docker will again start showing the same error. Example: I tried files with names other than Dockerfile, withe some file extensions etc. None worked.

Comment: The important difference from your original code is that this includes the entire directory `.` in the build context; in your original, the only thing you were sending to Docker was the `./Dockerfile`, and nothing else was available as a `COPY` source.